# Referencing a Hive view from within an AWS Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hive, aws-glue

I'm trying to figure out how to migrate a use case from EMR to AWS Glue involving Hive views.

In EMR today, I have Hive external tables backed by Parquet in S3, and I have additional views like `create view hive_view as select col from external_table where col = x`

Then in Spark on EMR, I can issue statements like `df = spark.sql("select * from hive_view")` to reference my Hive view.

I am aware I can use the Glue catalog as a drop-in replacement for the Hive metastore, but I'm trying to migrate the Spark job itself off of EMR to Glue.  So in my end state, there is no longer a Hive endpoint, only Glue.

Questions:

- How do I replace the `create view ...` statement if I no longer have an EMR cluster to issue Hive commands?  What's the equivalent AWS Glue SDK call?
- How do I reference those views from within a Glue job?

What I've tried so far: using `boto3` to call `glue.create_table` like this

```
glue = boto3.client('glue')
glue.create_table(DatabaseName='glue_db_name', 
   TableInput = {'Name': 'hive_view', 
       'TableType': 'VIRTUAL_VIEW',
       'ViewExpandedText': 'select .... from ...'
    })
```

I can see the object created in the Glue catalog but the classification shows as "Unknown" and the references in the job fail with a corresponding error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.getCatalogSource. : 
java.lang.Error: No classification or connection in bill_glue_poc.view_test at ...
```

I have validated that I can use Hive views with Spark in EMR with the Glue catalog as the metastore -- I see the view in the Glue catalog, and Spark SQL queries succeed, but I cannot reference the view from within a Glue job.

Comment: are you by any chance looking for this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html ?

Comment: I have already seen that doc and I am m aware that I can point an EMR cluster's Hive metastore at Glue.  But what I'm trying to do is reference Hive views from within a Glue job directly.

Comment: @wrschneider Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I haven't looked at this recently but I think there are some changes that allow Glue jobs to use objects in the Glue catalog directly from Spark as one would in EMR - see my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596569/tables-not-found-in-spark-sql-after-migrating-from-emr-to-aws-glue

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a temporary view in Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.3/api/R/createOrReplaceTempView.html) and query it like a Hive table (Scala):

```
val dataDyf = glueContext.getSourceWithFormat(
      connectionType = "s3",
      format = "parquet",
      options = JsonOptions(Map(
        "paths" -> Array("s3://bucket/external/folder")
      ))).getDynamicFrame()

// Convert DynamicFrame to Spark's DataFrame and apply filtering
val dataViewDf = dataDyf.toDF().where(...)

dataViewDf.createOrReplaceTempView("hive_view")

val df = spark.sql("select * from hive_view")
```

Comment: I'm not asking about temporary views.  I'm asking about persistent Hive views, which can be queried in Spark like Hive tables.

Comment: Temp view gives a possibility to achieve the same result as using external hive table. So yes, it's a workaround for you problem but not exact solution.