# Tables not found in Spark SQL after migrating from EMR to AWS Glue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I have Spark jobs on EMR, and EMR is configured to use the Glue catalog for Hive and Spark metadata.

I create Hive external tables, and they appear in the Glue catalog, and my Spark jobs can reference them in Spark SQL like `spark.sql("select * from hive_table ...")`

Now, when I try to run the same code in a Glue job, it fails with "table not found" error.  It looks like Glue jobs are not using the Glue catalog for Spark SQL the same way that Spark SQL would running in EMR.

I can work around this by using Glue APIs and registering dataframes as temp views:

`create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(...).toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(...)`

but is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: How did you created spark object? Did you enable enableHiveSupport() with it?

Comment: `glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())` and then `spark = glueContext.spark_session`

Comment: Are you trying to run your Glue jobs in EMR ?

Comment: No, the opposite, trying to run something that would have worked in EMR on Glue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a much awaited feature request (to use Glue Data Catalog with Glue ETL jobs) which has been release recently.
When you create a new job, you'll find the following option

`Use Glue data catalog as the Hive metastore`

You may also enable it for an existing job by editing the job and adding `--enable-glue-datacatalog` in the job parameters providing no value

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `SparkContext.getOrCreate()`, you should use `SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()`, with `enableHiveSupport()` being the important part that's missing. I think what's probably happening is that your Spark job is not actually creating your tables in Glue but rather is creating them in Spark's embedded Hive metastore, since you have not enabled Hive support.

Answer (score 1):

in my case

```
SparkSession.builder
      .config(
        "hive.metastore.client.factory.class",
        "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It was working on my Dev endpoint but not the actual ETL job. It is fixed by editing the job from Spark 2.2 to Spark 2.4.